# GWT - put a black border ac around a canvas

Tags: html, gwt

I am looking for a way to add a canvas in GWT with a black border, so that if the canvas background color is white i will see its boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Element, set the style:

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html

```
Canvas canvas  = Canvas.createIfSupported();
canvas.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor('black');
canvas.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);
canvas.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(1,Unit.PX);
```